# How to initialize one-to-many relationship in spring-data-jpa in data.sql initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring-dta-jpa application.  Before running some JUnit tests, I want to populate the embedded H2 database.  I know that this can be done by putting a data.sql file into the resource folder of my maven project as described in the spring doc.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

My question is:  How do I initialize parent child ("one-to-many") relationships in that data.sql file?  I do not know the IDs of the parent when I like to insert the child entities.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Long as an ID (and not UUID) then more likely your IDs would start from 1 and match the same order as records appeared in your data.sql

Examples of Entity relations:

```
@Entity
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length=256)
    @Size(min=1,max=256)
    private String name;

    private String code;

    private Date date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<DocumentItem> documentItems;


@Entity(name="document_item")
public class DocumentItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length=256)
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Document document;
```

In example above the column document_id would be added to document_item entity.

You also may specify the column name with JoinColumn annotation which is used for relation, for example:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
private Publisher publisher;
```

Example initialization script:

```
INSERT INTO document(name, code) VALUES ('Test Document 1', 'TD-1'); 
INSERT INTO document(name, code) VALUES ('Test Document 2', 'TD-2');
INSERT INTO document(name, code) VALUES ('Test Document 3', 'TD-3');
INSERT INTO document(name, code) VALUES ('Test Document 4', 'TD-4');
INSERT INTO document(name, code) VALUES ('Test Document 5', 'TD-5');

INSERT INTO document_item(document_id, name, price) VALUES (2,'Test Item 2.A', 100.45); 
INSERT INTO document_item(document_id, name, price) VALUES (2,'Test Item 2.B', 30.45);
INSERT INTO document_item(document_id, name, price) VALUES (2,'Test Item 2.C', 564);
INSERT INTO document_item(document_id, name, price) VALUES (4,'Test Item 4.A', 1);
INSERT INTO document_item(document_id, name, price) VALUES (4,'Test Item 4.B', 456);
INSERT INTO document_item(document_id, name, price) VALUES (5,'Test Item 5.A', 67);
INSERT INTO document_item(document_id, name, price) VALUES (2,'Test Item 2.D', 98);
```

Comment: You write "more likely your IDs would start from 1" ... that is not "just a likely concidence" (Meanwhile I found out that) one can _configure_ how IDs are generated by the DB.  @GeneratedValue((strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)   or      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", allocationSize = 10)      The latter will give you sequential numbering.

Comment: @Robert, you are right. I just didn't get so deep into details about ID generation strategy but left some space for that saying ".. likely.."